# How to create a dictionary from a dataframe, being the index the only key?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe called `la_crime_refined` that looks like the following:

```
    DR_NO       AREA NAME   LOCATION              LAT       LON
0   10304468    Southwest   1100 W 39TH PL        34.0141   -118.2978
1   190101086   Central     700 S HILL ST         34.0459   -118.2545
2   201418201   Pacific     4700 LA VILLA MARINA  33.9813   -118.4350
3   191501505   N Hollywood 5400 CORTEEN PL       34.1685   -118.4019
4   191921269   Mission     14400 TITUS ST        34.2198   -118.4468
```

I want to create a dictionary including the Latitudes and longitudes with a unique key: the index. I've tried this:

```
crime_cord = la_crime_refined[['LAT','LON']].to_dict(orient='index')
```

However, it returns the key names 'LAT' and 'LON' for every entry on the dictionary.

```
{0:{'LAT':34.0141,'LON',-118.2978},1:{...}...}
```

Is there any way to get an output that looks like this:

```
{0:(34.0141,-118.2978),1:(...)...}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind taking an additional step, you could simply iterate over the dictionary you get back from the `to_dict`-method:

```
res = {}
for k, v in la_crime_refined[['LAT','LON']].to_dict(orient='index').items():
    res[k] = (v['LAT'], v['LON'])
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over the rows of the dataframe (loop or dict-comprehension), e.g.

```
res = {idx: (row['LAT'], row['LON']) for idx, row in la_crime_refined.iterrows()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the format in the {'LAT'=X, 'LON'=Y}, the easiest way might be to simply use it as a basis to generate the format you desire:

```
old_format = {0:{'LAT':34.0141,'LON':-118.2978}, 1:{'LAT':50.0141,'LON':-120.2978}, 2:{'LAT':60,'LON':-130}}
print(old_format)
new_format = {}
for key in old_format.keys():
    new_format[key] = (old_format[key]['LAT'], old_format[key]['LON'])        
print(new_format)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: tuple(v.values()) for k, v in crime_cord.items()}
```